# arsort an array when some values are arrays themselves

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array that looks like:

```
array(5) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/288"
  ["title2"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/290"
  ["title3"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/284"
  ["title4"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/275"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/274"
  }
  ["title5"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/292"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/291"
  }
}
```

i want to arsort the arrays which works just fine as long as my value isnt an array in itself. if i `arsort($array);` it gives this:

```
array(5) {
  ["title5"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/292"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/291"
  }
  ["title4"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/275"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/274"
  }
  ["title2"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/290"
  ["title"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/288"
  ["title3"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/284"
}
```

but i want it to be this:

```
array(5) {
  ["title5"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/292"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/291"
  }
  ["title2"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/290"
  ["title"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/288"
  ["title3"]=>
  string(22) "http://example.com/284"
  ["title4"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/275"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://example.com/274"
  }
}
```

so basically i want to sort array from high to low in the url preserving keys, but when i arsort it puts the values that are arrays at the top of the list regardless of the number in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** switched to `uasort` as suggested by @xpapad

You should use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and implement your own comparison function, perhaps:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp(is_array($a) ? $a[0] : $a, is_array($b) ? $b[0] : $b);

});
```

Comment: `function cmp($a, $b) {
  return strcmp(is_array($a) ? $a[0] : $a, is_array($b) ? $b[0] : $b);
}
uasort($fruits, "cmp");`
is what i ended up using, your exact code threw an error for me. works perfectly otherwise tho thank you!

Comment: @user575594 What is your PHP version?

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirements are not well-defined. How should the sort behave for the following array?

```
$myarray = array(
    'title1' => array( '1000', '800' ),
    'title2' => 900
);
```

You example seems to assume that this scenario is not possible and that all values within an inner array cannot be interrupted by any value outside that array, is that the case?

If that is so, you should use custom sorting as @Dor-Shemer suggested, but use ***uasort*** rather than ***usort*** to maintain key-values association.

Comment: point for `uasort()` preserving keys was important. thank you

Comment: i only just now understood your answer. i suppose yes it is possible for the inner array to be interrupted by an outer value, however inner array values must always stay together regardless since they have a common key. trying to wrap my head around how this will affect sorting.